# Ler arquivo em binário

Tags: c, arquivo, imagem, edição-de-imagens

Olá, estou salvando um arquivo em formato binário e tentando abrir o mesmo binário. Porém, não estou obtendo o resultado esperado. Seguem a função de escrita e a de leitura. Estou salvando uma imagem de formato .ppm, porém quando tento trazer a mesma de volta para arquivo ASCII para ler a mesma como texto só consigo pegar o cabeçalho da mesmo; Além disso a imagem só é impressa com o mesmo código da original, nos casos que eu testei a cada x linhas onde linhas é o número de colunas, ou seja, em uma imagem 1024 x 768 ela imprime o mesmo da original a cada 1024 pixeis.
[Imagens de formato PPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format)

```
   //passa o arquivo para binario
    arquivo = fopen("imagem.bin", "wb");
    fwrite(&tipo, 1, sizeof (tipo), arquivo); //salva o tipo do arquivo
    fwrite(&larg, 1, sizeof (int), arquivo); //salva a largura da imagem
    fwrite(&alt, 1, sizeof (int), arquivo); // salva a altura do arquivo
    fwrite(&max, 1, sizeof (int), arquivo); // salva o valor máximo para cor arquivo

    for (i = 0; i < alt; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < larg; j++){
            fwrite(&imagem[i][j].r, 1 , sizeof (int), arquivo); /*salva as componentes*/
            fwrite(&imagem[i][j].g, 1 , sizeof (int), arquivo); /*do arquivo em forma de*/
            fwrite(&imagem[i][j].b, 1 , sizeof (int), arquivo); /*nova linha para cada cor*/
        }
    }
    fclose(arquivo);

    //abre a imagem em binário somente para leitura
    arquivo = fopen("imagem.bin", "rb");
    fread(code, 1, sizeof(code), arquivo);
    fread(&larg, 1, sizeof(int), arquivo);
    fread(&alt, 1, sizeof(int), arquivo);
    fread(&max, 1, sizeof(int), arquivo);

    for (i = 0; i < alt; i++){
        for (i = 0; i < larg; i++){
            fread(&imagem[i][j].r, 1, sizeof(int), arquivo);
            fread(&imagem[i][j].g, 1, sizeof(int), arquivo);
            fread(&imagem[i][j].b, 1, sizeof(int), arquivo);
        }
    }
    fclose(arquivo);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está salvando um padrão de bits que representa números. Entretanto, no formato PPM, você deve salvar os números como texto.

Ou seja, use `fprintf` ao invés de `fwrite`. Para a leitura, você pode tentar usar um `fscanf` ou um `fgets`.

EDIT:

No seu caso, já que está usando o P6, ele é um formato híbrido. O cabeçalho é texto, mas o *payload* é binário. De acordo com [esta especificação](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html%20aqui):

> 1. A "magic number" for identifying the file type. A ppm image's magic number is the two characters "P6".
> 2. Whitespace (blanks, TABs, CRs, LFs).
> 3. A width, formatted as ASCII characters in decimal.
> 4. Whitespace.
> 5. A height, again in ASCII decimal.
> 6. Whitespace.
> 7. The maximum color value (Maxval), again in ASCII decimal. Must be less than 65536 and more than zero.
> 8. A single whitespace character (usually a newline).
> 9. A raster of Height rows, in order from top to bottom. Each row consists of Width pixels, in order from left to right. Each pixel is a triplet of red, green, and blue samples, in that order. Each sample is represented in pure binary by either 1 or 2 bytes. If the Maxval is less than 256, it is 1 byte. Otherwise, it is 2 bytes. The most significant byte is first.

Traduzindo para o português:

> 1. Um "número mágico" para identificar o tipo do arquivo. O número mágico de uma imagem ppm é os dois caracteres "P6".
> 2. Espaços em branco (brancos, TABs, CRs, LFs).
> 3. A largura, formatada em caracteres ASCII em decimal.
> 4. Espaços em branco.
> 5. A altura, novamente em ASCII decimal.
> 6. Espaços em branco.
> 7. O valor máximo da cor (Maxval), novamente em ASCII decimal. Deve ser menos que 65536 e mais que zero.
> 8. Um único caractere de espaço em branco (normalmente uma quebra de linha).
> 9. Uma rasterização com um número de linhas igual a altura, de cima para baixo. Cada linha consiste de um número de pixels igual a largura, da esquerda para a direita. Cada pixel contém uma tripla das amostras de vermelho, verde e azul, nesta ordem. Cada amostra é representada puramente em binário por 1 ou 2 bytes. Se o Maxval é menor que 256, ele é de 1 byte. Caso contrário, é de 2 bytes. O byte mais significante é o primeiro.

Concluindo, você deve mudar a parte que escreve e lê o cabeçalho para usar números como texto. A parte da leitura é mais complexa devido ao fato de você ter que pular uma quantidade arbitrária de espaços em branco, ignorar comentários e ter que fazer a conversão de texto para número, além de decidir se cada amostra tem 1 ou 2 bytes. Mas como você afirma que já fez isso, então deverá ser fácil.

Comment: Então, no formato ppm quando é especificado P3 é por texto, porém o parâmetro P6 indica que ele é salvo em binário, tanto que a implementação dele por texto eu tenho pronta.

Comment: @pmargreff Ok, editei a resposta, veja se agora ficou legal.